# Bootstrap 3 - No margin/padding with grid system on small devices

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a bootstrap form. It display on my desktop as it should display. But when i change the screen size to tablet size or smaller, there is no padding/margin between date-number and subject-private.

I know the fix, that's not the problem. But i think i did'nt use the correct bootstrap-structure, because i assume that bootstrap normally does this for you?

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <label>Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Number">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="date" id="date" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Date">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <label>Subject</label>
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><label>Private?</label></p>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="private" value="1">Yes</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="private" value="0">No</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

So can anyone tell me what i did wrong here?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong. Just control the padding on the `.container` using a `@media()` query. Afterall, Bootstrap is a framework and you have to implement your own requirements if they aren't present

Comment: Saying that, i've just noticed you're using `.row`, try using `.container` and see if that works. If my memory is right `.row` has no padding unlike `.container`

Comment: Container should not be nested at this level. You are supposed to have a container in the upper level of your website and then you have rows and cols inside of it, respectively.

Comment: @yBrodsky indeed, I was just saying to *try* it to see if it had the desired effect. `.row` should be in a `.container` yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's indeed some misuse. Here is an example:

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Label</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="whatever">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Label</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="whatever">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--some more rows if you have, or whatever. This is just an example -->
</form>
```

Comment: But the OP has 2 different rows, with 2 cols each?

Comment: So? I was lazy. The second row comes right below the row I have

Comment: So I don't see anything different to what the OP actually has? `.row` > `.col-*`.

Comment: Look again, this is the right syntax as per the docs. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example

Comment: Ah yes I see, apologies, you moved the `.form-group`. Probably worth explaining the difference

Comment: Thanks. Ill give it a try tonight and will let you know. First having my diner.

Comment: But, where in the docs do you see form groups inside a grid system? I cant seem to find it.

Comment: Beside that i could'nt find it in the docs, this was the solution.